# Linux software center cannot run anymore

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation

I am using Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon.

Linux Mint has Software Center, just like Ubuntu Software Center in Ubuntu. After LinuxMint installation, I could run the software center in my system. But someday, may be after some operation like remove OpenJDK, install Oracle JDK,...the Software Center doesn't run anymore. When I click the Software Center icon or run from Terminal, the OS ask for super user password too, after entered the password, the round-spin (waiting) cursor appear for some seconds. After all, nothing happen. The Software Center doesn't run. Something I tried:

1. Reinstall default JRE (OpenJRE)
2. remove `software-manager` and reinstall `software-manager`

This is the output when I try to run `sudo mintinstall`

```
$ sudo mintinstall
Vector smash protection is enabled.
add_categories took 13.497 ms
build_matched_packages took 0.298 ms
add_packages took 3828.769 ms
First run detected, initial set of reviews used
add_reviews took 1022.018 ms
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintinstall/mintinstall.py", line 1920, in <module>
    Application()
  File "/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintinstall/mintinstall.py", line 59, in wrapper
    res = func(*arg)
  File "/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintinstall/mintinstall.py", line 617, in __init__
    sans26 = ImageFont.truetype(self.FONT, 26)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 239, in truetype
    return FreeTypeFont(font, size, index, encoding)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 128, in __init__
    self.font = core.getfont(font, size, index, encoding)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 37, in __getattr__
    raise ImportError("The _imagingft C module is not installed")
ImportError: The _imagingft C module is not installed
```

Comment: Can you provide the terminal output you get?

Comment: @burian.vlastimil: I check all of three packages you mentioned, python-pil, aptdaemon, python-pkg-resources, all of them are installed and nothing would be install new.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev libfreetype6`

Comment: please see edit and uninstall the offending package

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

```
sudo pip uninstall pil
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL
```

Linux Mint has its own "software center" called `mintinstall`

You may find if it is installed with:

```
apt-cache policy mintinstall
```

As it is an essential part of the Linux Mint system, it *should* be installed.

However, if it is not, although I can't imagine how you removed it, you can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install mintinstall
```

In any case, I don't recommend using Ubuntu's software center on Linux Mint.

It is also possible you have some broken packages, to attempt to fix this, run:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Another possibility is, that some packages are not yet configured, to fix that, run:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

After these two commands, you should be able to install/remove software with `apt`.

So, if you fixed some packages' dependencies and configured all packages, you may safely run:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

And further install anything you like.

If this answer does not solve your problem, please do comment. I will try to assist you further.

**Further, it seems `mintinstall` needs OpenJDK, you can install it as follows:**

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre-headless
```

Comment: Thank for your detail tutorial. I followed it, but I got the error message, I updated it at the bottom of the question.

Comment: @verdana see comments and check those packages